# Java use Yacc Grammar for custom syntax recognition

Tags: java, bison, yacc

I got a Yacc file (foo.y) that has the grammar for a custom language.
I now want to use this grammar in a java project for stuff like syntax-highlighting, syntax checking etc.
Is there a way to transfer the Yacc grammar into a java usable format ? 
I know its a little broad of a question, but just a hint would be really helpfull.

Comment: I guess you can adjust the yacc file to produce a format you can use in java to specify highlighting and stuff... but really, the question is too broad to be topical here.

Comment: Bison has an (experimental) option to [generate Java parsers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Java-Parsers). Alternatively, you could try one of the many [Java LALR parser generators](https://www.google.com.pe/search?q=java+lalr+parser+generator)